# Copying legend in QGIS Map layout

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend, mapping, copy

I am creating a map where I have many legend items. Initially, I divided them into two columns but now I want to separate them. When they were together I have customised font size, style etc.

[image: Legend with two columns]

I can create a new legend entry however I am looking for a shortcut where I can copy(duplicate) the existing legends and after pasting I can do the alteration. In items I could see the option of "copy item" but I do not know how to paste the legend for further modification.

[image: Screenshot for copying legend item]

Answer (score 1):

I could do that by right-clicking on legend item and "copy" it first.

[image]

Later, I have to go to menu bar "Edit --> Paste" to get the work done.

[image]